# iOS SnapKit and scenes

Tags: ios, swift

I have made a storyboard with one scene. In my `UIViewController` I have defined following using SnapKit:

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    emailTextField.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.size.equalTo(CGSizeMake(100, 40))
    }
}
```

I keep getting error:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
```

I have tried `snp_remakeConstraints` and `snp_updateConstraints` too but same error.

What am I  doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: You likely need to add a location constraint rather than just having size constraints.

Try `make.top.left.equalTo(self.view)` in addition to the size constraint you have already set.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem occurs, because SnapKit removes only your `emailTextField`'s own constraints (by setting automatically `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`), so there are still some duplicates.

For the storyboard constraints you need to clear all default constraints. You can achieve that using the following piece of code:

`yourTextFieldsSuperviewName.removeConstraints(view.constraints)`

Good luck!